# Hot water recirculation questions should be on-topic

Tags: discussion

I don't think [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/252832/recirculating-bridge-valves-that-close-at-higher-temperatures-than-95f) should have been closed/marked off-topic. It's clearly a home improvement question, in fact the solution I personally ended up going with was DIY (the domain of this page is *diy.homeimprovement.stackexchange*), a solution I can't share now because the question was closed.

The first few comments on the topic were fair: please provide an image, more details, etc., which I did end up providing. But the flippant, patronizing responses of some of the commenters ("nOt EvErythIng Is On AmAzOn") suggest the question was closed out of ignorance rather than a violation of any specific policy.

Lastly: I can't find any specific policy rules anywhere in the help center. Is it really just up to the whims of the 6 or so people with the VtC privilege?

I'll also point out [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/254838/where-can-i-get-a-cover-for-a-main-supply), highly upvoted with multiple answers that's literally someone asking if a part exists (just like my question). How is the above on-topic if mine is off-topic?

Comment: `the domain of this page is diy.homeimprovement.stackexchange`. No, no it's not... :shrug:

Answer (score 2):

See this [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy. There's also a section in our [help page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that describes what questions are on and off topic for the site.

Comment: Opinion: Techniques are on topic. "Is it possible" usually is. "What is this functional fungus attached to my house called and what does it do"  usually are. "Does it exist" can be made more on-topic by structuring it as 'Here's the problem; how do I solve it (I imagine this kind of thing might work, but there may be better answers)". "What kinds of stores might carry" is marginal, "recommend a store or specific make/model" is pretty clearly out of bounds... But all lines are fractal and/or fuzzy, and humans aren't completely consistent, and there are always going to be cases of disagreement.

Comment: Since the linked question was deleted, what they were asking was "AFAIK this valve's temperatures are not adjustable, but are there valves on the market that are adjustable and keep the valve open until higher temperatures are reached?" and the community closed it.

Comment: 'Are x on the market" often gets classified as a shopping question, since a yes answer us useless unless models and sources are named... so you might as well just start shopping